# Solved - Pop Up Dialog gone after insert a Object/ Mesh when click in free Space then, how to bring it back?

Tags: objects, interface, edit-mode, import

Win 10

Its a Beginner Q.

How to get this Popup Dialogbox back? Or where i can find that Object Parameters?

I insert Object via Shift+A. The Popup instant open also, but if i click in a free Space
the Box is gone and i can´t bring it back by...logical way...click the object again.

Cheers.

---

I get it.

F9 works for that Setting Box. After eg. "shade smooth" you cant get back this Popup.

Comment: This is the default behavior of blender. If you have clicked away, but haven't done any other actions after that, you can press F9 to bring back the "object properties" box, but other than that, the ability to continuousely modify a primitive's parameters after adding (and then clicking away) is not coming until 2.9. However, if you want to find info about the object's transforms, press N (gives different info in object and edit mode). You can also find this information in the Object Properties tab.

Comment: F9 does nothing except a little Box opens "toggle edit mode" that do just nothing if i click that. Object Properties tab i check that...That sadly dont shows Torus Segments or Radius Options and similar params.
I watch a Blender Guru Tutorial and he say also you cant get this Settings back...this is...-.-*